# table row after clone datepicker not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i m try to clone table row, it is clone the row perfectly, but datepicker not working after clone the row, please help me any one to solve this

my code is

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="mytab">
            <thead>
              <tr class="tr_clone"> 
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>JOB SITE</th>
                <th>APPROVED</th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr id="id1" class="tr_clone">
                <td><div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker-autoclose" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calender"></i></span> </div>
                                </div></td>
                <td><textarea class="form-control"></textarea></td>

                <td><select class="form-control">
         <option value="">test</option>
         <option value="CM">CMM2</option>

        </select></td>

        <td align="center"><div class="checkbox checkbox-success"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"><label for="checkbox"></label></div></td>

        <td><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add btn btn-block btn-default"></td>

              </tr>

            </tbody>
          </table>
```

scrip is in image

[image]

datepicker script is

```
<script src="plugins/bower_components/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

jQuery('.mydatepicker, #datepicker').datepicker();
jQuery('#datepicker-autoclose').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});

jQuery('#date-range').datepicker({
    toggleActive: true
});
jQuery('#datepicker-inline').datepicker({

    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Comment: working link is [link](http://webparktech.com/demoworksmartpro/holiday.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datepicker has to be initialized on the cloned row input. You should use a delegated event and onfocus which would be quicker if you had a lot of rows.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/): "Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time."

jQuery 1.7+ use .on()

```
 $('table').on('focus', 'input.mydatepicker:not(.hasDatepicker)', function () {
    $('.mydatepicker').datepicker();
});
```

otherwise use .bind() or .live()

**Update:** 
the class 'hasDatepicker' could be added to the cloned row and should be removed since it hasn't been initialized yet.

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yodzz89o/)